# New Date API - Add Era

Tags: java, java-time

I'm playing with the new Date API and, just out of curiosity, I've tried to run the following code:

```
LocalDateTime timePoint = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Canberra"));

System.err.println(timePoint.plus(1, ChronoUnit.ERAS));
```

And got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Era (valid values 0 - 1): 2
       at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(ValueRange.java:311)
       at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:703)
       at java.time.LocalDate.with(LocalDate.java:1023)
       at java.time.LocalDate.plus(LocalDate.java:1245)
       at java.time.LocalDateTime.plus(LocalDateTime.java:1194)
       at pt.sibs.epms.Tester.method6(Tester.java:79)
       at pt.sibs.epms.Tester.main(Tester.java:59)
```

Is this a bug or I just am not using it correctly?

Comment: What did you expect would happen and why do you think the actual behaviour would be a bug? It works according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) which says: "throws DateTimeException if the addition cannot be made". The standard (ISO) calendar has only two eras (BCE = before common era and CE = common era). There's no era after the current era (CE).

Comment: Honestly, I was not expecting anything, I was just trying the API. I was mostly intrigued by the error message: "Invalid value for Era (valid values 0 - 1): 2", it seems odd. If you try FOREVER instead of ERAS, you get "Unsupported unit", which makes sense.

Comment: I would say, this examples proves that it is complete nonsense to use eras as time units at all - with the exception of Japanese calendar. Calendar specific units would have been much better as design choice. Jespers answer about the concrete reason is right (after current gregorian era there is no next era)..

Comment: In case no one noticed, I was talking about the error message:

"Invalid value for Era (valid values 0 - 1): 2"

Comment: Yes, and Jespers answer exactly addresses your error message. Pseudo code: "date-with-era-value-1" plus "one era" = "date-with-era-value-2" (invalid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) of the `plus` method that you are calling says:

> Throws: `DateTimeException` if the addition cannot be made

You are using the standard ISO chronology, which uses [`IsoEra`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoEra.html). The ISO chronology has two eras:

- BCE = before current era (before the year 0)
- CE = current era (starting from the year 0)

If you have a date which is in the CE and you try to go to the next era, you get a `DateTimeException` because there is no next era, so the addition cannot be made and the exception is thrown, which is according to the documentation, so this is not a bug.